# Illegal start of expression while throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement, custom-exceptions, throws

I keep getting the error Illegal start of expression in this part of the code.

```
switch(length) {
    case 1: if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("End")){    
        throws new AnotherException("Stop",true);
    } else {
        throws new AnotherException("Continue",false); 
    } 
    break;
}
```

Specifically if I add

```
throw new AnotherException
```

Can someone explain the reason why it causes this error? Thanks.

Comment: "This part" is a bit broad

Answer (score 0):

You need to change keyword `throws` to `throw`.

When throwing an Exception, `throw` is used and `throws` is used in method signatures to indicate expected exceptions from that method.

Change `throws new AnotherException("Continue",false);`   to `throw new AnotherException("Continue",false);`

Answer (score 0):

Various errors:

- your method must **handle the exception** with `throws AnotherException`
- **use `throw` instead of `throws`**
- `break` statement is  **unreachable code** and wont allow compile because both sides of the `if` solve throwing an `Exception`.

So your code must look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AnotherException {
    String message = "End";
    int length = 1;
    switch (length) {
    case 1:
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("End")) {
            throw new AnotherException("Stop", true);
        } else {
            throw new AnotherException("Continue", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use throw instead of throws. Throws is used to declare the possibility of a thrown exception after the method head.

```java
yourMethod(...) throws AnotherException {
    //stuff....

    switch(length)
    {
        case 1: if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("End")){    
                    throw new AnotherException("Stop",true);
                }
                else{
                    throw new   AnotherException("Continue",false); 
                } break;

    //stuff...
}
```

Comment: It is obviously just an example to demonstrate the difference of throw/throws.

Comment: ok, this code is a bad example because wont compile, thus, wont solve question completely